# How to get id from records which satisfy the condition laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have below data in my users table.

```
postgres=# select id,customers from users limit 2;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id        | 2
customers | {
   "regular":[],
   "prime":[
      {
         "email":"test1@example.com",
         "payment_pending":true,
      },
      {
         "email":"test2@example.org",
         "payment_pending":false,
      }
   ]
}
-[ RECORD 2 ]-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id        | 3
customers | {
   "regular":[
      {
         "email":"test3@example.com",
      }
   ],
   "prime":[
      
   ]
}
```

Now I want the list of IDs from the above table where the given email should present in customers->prime with `payment_pending` **true**. Can anyone help me with this? You can use `test1@example.com` email and write the query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what is `prime`? is it a relation? is it type or something else?

if `users` has one to many relation with `customers`, there is function `whrerHas`:

definition of `whereHas` function:

```
Model::whrerHas('relation_name', function($query) {
    $query->where('column_name', 'operator', 'value');
})
```

if you need to pass parameter after function use `use($your_parameters)` Like:

```
Model::whrerHas('relation_name', function($query) use($parameter1, $parameter2) {
    $query->where('column_name', 'operator', 'value');
})
```

after `$query` you can use any condition functions Like (`where`, `orWhere`, `whereIn` etc) for target table(table that you use in `relation_name`).

in your case maybe this work:

```
User::whereHas('customers', function($query) use($email) {
     $query->where('email', $email)
           ->where('payment_pending ', true);
})
```

Comment: `prime` is just an entry in `customers` it is not a relation. The given query is giving **BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method** error. Is it possible to modify the query? Thanks.